# Is there any way I can see my own previous questions?

Tags: discussion

I found an answer to previous question which was emailed to me on 5.03.2013. That e-mail suggested that I try a couple of things, and it says

'Please let us know.

- Stack Exchange Team'.

I am trying to let the Stack Exchange Team know.

I couldn't find a sensible tag that would enable me to submit and wasn't able to create one, so I had to choose one that is meaningless.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what is actually happening here, your question is a bit vague and without further information its kinda hard to understand what situation you are referring to.